# R Cairo pdf fonts unreadable in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: r, cairo, adobe-illustrator

I cannot get pdf files created using the Cairo package to open in Illustrator with readable text.  Any advice wjhy this is happening?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)
df = data.frame(x=rnorm(2000), y=rnorm(2000), v=abs(rnorm(2000)^5))
p = ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=v, size=v), alpha=0.75) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10)
print(p)

Cairo(file='out/plot.pdf', type='pdf', width=4, height=4, bg="transparent", unit="in", dpi=72) 
p
dev.off()
browseURL('out/plot.pdf')
```

This document looks fine in R and when the pdf is opened in SumatraPDF etc, but when opened in Illustrator it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is really just a problem with your Illustrator setup.

Comment: Well ggsave doesn't have this problem, but it instead creates ellipses that read into Illustrator as q's, hence the need for Cairo..

Answer (score 0):

use ggplot2 function ggsave, with the para `useDingbats=FALSE`:

```
ggsave(plot=p,height=6,width=6,dpi=200, filename="plot.pdf", useDingbats=FALSE)
```